# What does the two dot before a table name mean

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've seen a query that looks like this:

```
Select Id from ..TableName where [Name] = @MyName
```

I can't seem to find when, or why this would be used. The query session is run against a database (So there is a USE already), and then 'TableName' is in both the default schema (dbo) as well as an audit schema (audit.TableName).

What would the .. mean in this case, and is it required / useful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server has a four-part naming convention for table references:

```
<server name>.<database name>.<schema name>.<table name>
```

Often the server is left off.

The `..` occurs when you are happy to use the default schema in the database you are referencing.  The default is usually `dbo`, but of course you can change it to something else.  So, generally, it means:

```
from <current database>.dbo.TableName
```

Comment: Thanks. So would there be any benefit of using this notation, vs omitting the '..'? i.e. SELECT Id FROM TableName ... ?

Comment: for performance reasons you should at least put in the schema. just so that sql doesn't have to go through all the schemas looking for it, and this might save you a few thousands of a second. but then one could argue what if the object changes schemas then all objects referencing it need to change. 
here is Brent Ozar opening a can of worms on it: 
https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/05/why-use-schemas/